# Folder create on desktop when playing

Tags: league-of-legends

For several weeks now it appears that Leage of Legends is creating untitled folders on the desktop of my MacBook (the newest MacBook Pro Touch Bar) during playing. It seems random, sometimes only one or two when I play 10 parties, sometimes a lot of them. Sometimes it even creates a `.zip` of a folder. I asked Apple about this bug and they don't know why it is happening.

Is this intended League behavior or is it something worse?

Comment: Is there anything in these folders? If so what is it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. No, these folders are empty.

Comment: This is just a hunch but if you use a shortcut, see if it doesn't have arguments in the target field. For example in the target you could have "C:\Program Files\Riot Games\LoL.exe -debug"

Comment: It's on a Mac, there's no setup type.

Comment: When you have a problem with a software not made by Apple, it's usually better to ask the developers of that software and not Apple support.

Answer (score -2):

I was unable to find a definitive solution to this problem but found a few threads on the Lol forums/boards that even date back to 2013 about this :

- [Here](https://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/bug-report/ZWEdUJmt-client-mac-untitled-folders-upon-exiting-game)
- [This one too](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=3849581)
- [This one suggests](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=3573549) enabling software mouse as a solution
- [This one suggests](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=3287456&page=1), on page 2, to use windowed boderless mode
- [This one suggests](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=4154814) just to use one monitor when playing lol